# Is this base 62 encoding algorithm okay?

Tags: scala, converting

This Scala code snippet is supposed to encode a SHA1 hash in base 62.

Can you find any issues? I'm asking since I might not be able to change the algorithm and, for example, fix issues in the future.

I'd like to be able to also implement it in JavaScript in the future.

```
def mdSha1() = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1") // not thread safe

def hashSha1Base62DontPad(text: String): String = {
  val bytes = mdSha1().digest(text.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  val bigint = new java.math.BigInteger(1, bytes)
  val result = encodeInBase62(bigint)
  result
}

private val Base62Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

def encodeInBase62(number: BigInt): String = {
  // Base 62 is > 5 but < 6 bits per char.
  var result = new StringBuilder(capacity = number.bitCount / 5 + 1)
  var left = number
  do {
    val remainder = (left % 62).toInt
    left /= 62
    val char = Base62Alphabet.charAt(remainder)
    result += char
  }
  while (left > 0)
  result.toString
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 'standard' to have `0-9` at the beginning of the 'alphabet' for numbers....

I would have suggested that you use the native functionality in BigInteger to convert the value to a [String in any given radix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29), but unfortunately, it does not support more than radix 36. Still, you should follow that standard and start with `0-9` instead of ending with it.

I would also suggest two things:

- you should convert the alphabet to an array immediately:

  ```
  private val Base62Alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray()
  ```
- you should not have the magic number '62' in your code, but should base it off the array size:

  ```
  private val Radix = Base62Alphabet.length
  ```

  your code then becomes:

  ```
  val remainder = (left % Radix).toInt
  left /= Radix
  ```

Finally, I don't like that you have variable-length results from the conversion. You should ensure that all hashes of data with the same length have the same length of output... -left-padding with `0` as needed. It **is** possible for something to hash to 0x0000000000 (hex).... which will give you 0-value `number.bitCount`.

Comment: Thanks! Concerning the alphabet, Base64 uses "ABCD...abcd...0123+/" rather than "0123...ABC...abc+/" [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). I was thinking "Base64 but without the two last characters".

Comment: @KajMagnus you should be aware that if you were to use Base64 instead, it **will** be faster, and the bit-manipulations are much easier (and there are some easy-to-use libraries for it already).

Comment: On my computer, SHA1 + Base62 is 2.6 times slower than SHA1 + Base64. And running SHA1 + Base64 takes 5 microseconds. — I'll probably generate a URL safe base 64 string instead, and strip any '-'; that actually works fine in my particular use case, and is faster and simpler.